# Why can't target class in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navbar

i can't target className in react. I try to target it with `div className="navbar">` and `.navbar { align-items: center; }` but it doesnt work.

```
    div{
    display: block;
    background-color: rgb(211, 57, 57);
    font: sans-serif;
    color: #white; 
    
    
}
li {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    align-items: center;
}
ul {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
    align-items: center;
}
```

and navbar.js `

`

```
import React from 'react'
import './Navbar.css'

const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        
            <div className="navbar">
                <ul className="ul">
                    
                    <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: You have to actually add the css to the html. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: That would be javascript. But i use react : https://prnt.sc/2006wfk My Index.html code is totally different file, there is <div id="root"></div> where react injects and react doesnt render index.html since this is my react code https://prnt.sc/20075ge and this is html code https://prnt.sc/2007afv

Comment: React is just javascript with additional features for your convenience. You use css the same way in react as you do in js. Also, I'm saying that you should add css to your index.html file, not to any .js file.

Comment: Please read edit above. React injects in div id root, but in my index.html there is rotating Create react App whily in my index.js file there is just a navbar and when i go to localhost:3000 there is only that navbar (no Create react app).

Answer (score 0):

The rule `align-items: center;` is connected to using Flexbox, on itself it won't do much. Edit to match:

```
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Also remember that the default way for flex is to arrange the children horizontally, and `align-items` moves the children vertically in that case. If you want the children to stack vertically, you should add `flex-direction: column;`

Comment: I also used justify-content: space-between but spaces are 6cm long, how can I add 0,5cm spaces between horizontal items?

Answer (score 0):

Your index.html should look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/App.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

React has nothing to do with your css. You *can* use react to modify your css and you *can* use npm packages like material-ui to do the styling for you. But since you are clearly not doing either of those things, the above solution is the correct one.